# Change "Add New item" to "Add New task" for announcements in Sharepoint Online

Tags: list, office-365

How can we change the text

> Add new item

to

> Add new report

in a SharePoint Office 365 site?

Comment: You can use JSLink for that also.

Comment: Where is that text? Screenshot please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add CEWP to your page using below steps.**

1. Go to Page where you want to change the text for link.
2. On your page, click **Site Actions** and then click **Edit Page**
3. Click on the area where you want to add the Content Editor Web Part
4. The **Add Web Parts** dialog box will open. Choose the type of content that you would like to add. For us, scroll down to the **Media and Contents** section, click on **Content Editor** Web Part, and then click **Add**
5. The Web Part will be added to your page.
6. Edit the webpart & Click on **Click here to add new content**
7. Click on **Edit Source** in **Format Text** on the ribbon & paste below javascript in it.
8. Save the page.

Now CEWP will be added with below code on your page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementsByTagName("idHomePageNewItem").innerHTML="Add new report"
</script>
```

**Get your exact tag name using the DOM element of browser.**

As this is confusing for me because Announcement List always Shows "Add new announcement" & you have mentioned here "Add new item".

Name of such controls for every list/library are different.

Comment: can you tell me in which page i have to insert this script ?

Comment: on the same page from where the link is available or you want to remove the link.

Comment: am new to sharepoint , in sharepoint designer where i have to insert this script ? i mean which form Display form or edit form or new form ?

Comment: Open list in SharePoint designer.. add the given javascript inside the head of the page.

Comment: thank you . if u share screen shots it will be more helpful for me.'

Comment: Open Allitems.aspx page for the specific list..Find PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead in it & within that place the above code.

Comment: If this code does not work than use code of @Dikesh.. It will also work

Comment: Is it possible to attach images as attachments in "send a mail " Sharepoint Designer Action?

Comment: Please ask the same thing in new question with explanation in community.

Answer (score 3):

Add CEWP on your page and add below script in it.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function() {
      document.getElementById("idHomePageNewAnnouncement").getElementsByTagName("span")[1].innerHTML="Add new report";    
             };    
    </script>
```

## UPDATE

### Using JS link

- Put upper code in js file and upload it in Style Library.
- Edit the list view page and edit the list view web part and in
  **Miscellaneous** tab, there is one **JS link** property.
- In that textbox give your js file url i.e. ~sitecollection/Style Library/jsfilename.js

Hope this will help you!

Comment: this is a sharepoint subsite , so i cannot add CEWP and  work in CEWP. only limited rights given to desing this site, Is any other way to change Add new Item to Add New Report ?

Comment: Is it possible to attach images as attachments in "send a mail " Sharepoint Designer Action?

Comment: i used your above code to change new item to new Report , i got the error which is screened below

Comment: Web Part Error: Unknown server tag. Correlation ID: cc447d9d-409e-3000-a548-9875c410f38a.

Comment: Please check the id in your page from view source, and pass proper id. Also try it by commenting the code.

Comment: The upper script is working properly in my O365 account.

Comment: i placed the above code in allitem.aspx but again am getting the same error.,i cant edit my page with advance mode in Sharepoint Designer . can u give a solution for this?

Comment: and i have passed the correct id  in the script .

Comment: in url pass, .../allItems.aspx?contents=1 and remove that content editor webpart. And then check the page. and then re-add the CEWP

Comment: am not added any CEWP . i directly placed the above code in ALLItems.aspx page . but cant edit this ALLItem.aspx page in advanced Mode , all the line are hihlighted in yellow color background .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39937/discussion-between-dikesh-gandhi-and-azharuddin).